# Is there a way to add React-app link to an existing html dynamic website?

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, web, mern

So I have been making this project for college and I am completely new to **MERN stack**. I have made a *basic sorting visualizer using React* and a website using *basic web technologies*[html, css, js, bootstrap]; both separately.

Also, I have already initialized a repo of the website on **github** but I am unable to add or commit the copied files of '*sorting0*' in vs code.

Any guidance and help would be appreciated!

I have been trying to link the **React app** to my **website** for a while now by using -

`<a href="../sorting0/src/App.js">Sorting Visualizer</a>`

But it doesn't open the app.

My **React app** works fine when turned on using `npm start`; is there a way to do this in the **website**?
I searched a lot '*Linking React app to an existing website*', but it only results in '*adding hyperlink to React*'.

If there are other resources available, I would be grateful.

Comment: **other resources** - How about [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html)?

Comment: Alternatively, you can place the entire React app into an `iframe`

Comment: @RandyCasburn what I am trying to achieve is "the link" to open up in a new tab rendering my "React App". I am weirdly confused on how to do it without scripting everything inside my html.

Comment: `<a href="url-to-index.html-of-react-app-build" target="_blank">Open React APP</a>` <-- What is wrong with a simple hyperlink then?

Comment: @RandyCasburn I have been trying to do that but it opens up a blank page, no application or whatsoever. I don't know what to do. Can you guide me more?

Comment: This is what I call a "[where is Waldo"](https://www.123sonography.com/sites/default/files/article/images/2_Waldo_Illustration.png) question without knowing the details about Waldo, what Waldo is wearing, what Waldo looks like, what gender Waldo is, etc. I can guess until I get lucky, but I'm not sure that is the purpose of SO.  Please do your best to get everything in your git repository with the existing code and an explanation of where you want this link. I'll try to take a look at the issue for you if you can do that.

Comment: @RandyCasburn https://github.com/TheFall3n1/sorting0 this is the repo I have been pushing into and was hoping to link this app with https://github.com/TheFall3n1/Major-Project-Sem6 this repo's index.html. Tried putting both the files in the same repo but nothing happened. Confused....

Comment: I get the impression this is a homework project. If so, please read the [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: If this is homework or a project for school of some sort: If you're totally lost, then get help, real help. Get up with your instructor and arrange for one-on-one instruction as this will help you get back on your feet the quickest way possible. Best of luck, and much success!

Comment: Also, the _sorting0_ project does not build due to dependency issues in your package.json file.